Show that at a certain moment each car will be at its starting point.
At $n$ distinct points of a circular race course, $n$ cars are ready to start. Each of them covers the course in an hour. At a given signal every car selects one of the two possible directions and starts immediately. Whenever two cars meet both of them change directions and go on without loss of speed. Show that at a certain moment each car will be at its starting point.
This seems like an invariance/monovariance kind of question. I cannot find anything useful. Any hint would be appreciated.

Have you tried small examples with 2 or 3 cars to see what happens? Also note that you can equivalently say that instead of changing directions, the cars interchange speeds.

You can consider the cars as moving independently in the chosen directions, passing each other without interacting except for interchanging labels.  So after one hour the set of positions and velocities of your cars will be the same as the original positions
and velocities, and the labels will be some permutation $\pi$ of the originals.  If this permutation has order $m$, then after $m$ hours the cars have their original labels as well as positions and velocities.
